# Browsing the year in a string

Tags: visual-foxpro, foxpro

So I have a field containing dates; however not all years are the same. How do I browse for a specific year. I have tried the following, but it doesn't really work.

BROWSE FIELDS Lastcall FOR Lastcall LIKE '%2019%'

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OR.. exactly as you had it which will allow you to directly edit the records too.  IF the "LastCall" is a date based field

```
BROWSE FIELDS Lastcall FOR year( Lastcall ) = 2019
```

if it is a string field, you could do

```
BROWSE FIELDS Lastcall FOR '2019' $ Lastcall
```

The "$" means does the string on the left exist anywhere in the field on the right (which you could concatenate multiple string fields if you so wanted to.

Answer (score 2):

There's a number of ways you could do this.

Set a filter on the table:

```
SET FILTER TO YEAR(LastCall) = 2019
```

Use a select query:

```
SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE YEAR(LastCall) = 2019
```

If your table is really large I would suggest using the select statement.